# create ndarray from numpy memmap slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shared-memory

I am wondering how to determine if an object is a direct memmap object or a slice descendent of one.

The easiest way to as the question is with an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> filename = '../sandbox/test.bin'
>>> a = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', offset=0, shape=(4,2), order='F')
>>> print a
[[ 1.  5.]
 [ 2.  6.]
 [ 3.  7.]
 [ 4.  8.]]
>>> a.filename
'Z:\\CNI\\sandbox\\test.bin'
>>> a.shape
(4L, 2L)
>>> a.offset
0
>>>
>>> b = a[:,1]
>>> print b
[ 5.  6.  7.  8.]
>>> b.filename
'Z:\\CNI\\sandbox\\test.bin'
>>> b.shape
(4L,)
>>> b.offset
0
>>>
```

how would I determine that b is not a memmap object, but is instead a slice descendent of one?
Or at the very least that b's offset is wrong. (in this example the offset should be 4)

Comment: Check out the function `get_data_base` from [here](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/). I'm not 1000% sure it works with memmaps, but a priori it should.

Comment: @user3701099 in this example you can check the `OWNDATA` parameter of the `b.flags` attribute, which is `False` for a slice...

Comment: @SaulloCastro the OWNDATA in flags attribute works and is very straightforward

Comment: @eickenberg the get_data_base function also works from the link you post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you can check the `OWNDATA` parameter of the:

```
b.flags
```

attribute, which is `False` for a slice...